# $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ with finitely many discontinuities is integrable,provided $f$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, riemann-integration

I want to prove the following theorem:

**Theorem**

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be a bounded function on $[a,b]$,if $D_f$ is a finite set,then $f\in R([a,b])$.

Proof: Let $|f(x)|\leq M$ for every $x\in [a,b]$ $(M>0)$.

Suppose $D_f=\{a_1,...,a_k\}$

Let $\epsilon>0$,without loss take $\epsilon<4M(b-a)$

Consider $(a_i-\epsilon/4Mk,a_i+\epsilon/4Mk),i=1,2,...,k$

and remove those from $[a,b]$ to get a compact set $K$.

Now $f:K\to \mathbb R$ is continuous on $K$ and hence uniformly continuous.

So,given $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $x,y\in K \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2$

Choose $\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{2((b-a)-\epsilon/4M)}$.

Now the length of the set $K$ is $(b-a)-\epsilon/4M>0$

Divide it into $n(>1/\delta)$ subintervals of equal length.

and also adjoin the subintervals $[a_i-\epsilon/4Mk,a_i+\epsilon/4Mk]$ to get a partition $P=(x_0,x_1,...,x_{n+k})$ with $(n+k)$ subintervals.

Now $U(P,f)-L(P,f)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+k} (M_i-m_i)\Delta x_i<\delta\{(b-a)-\epsilon/4M\}+2Mk.(\epsilon/4Mk)<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$

Is the proof correctly done?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, $K$ is a compact interval with a bunch of open intervals removed. When you say "Divide it into $n(>1/\delta)$ subintervals of equal length", are you referring to $K$? If so, I don't think you can guarantee that you can decompose $K$ into intervals of equal length.

Comment: @user771918 why not? I can choose the size of removed intervals sufficiently small,so that the rest i.e. $K$ has a positive length and it is a composition of intervals.Now can I not choose $n$ sufficienly large so that each subinterval is of size $||K||/n$ where $||K||$ is the length of $K$.

Comment: @user771918 Ok ignore the work equal,I just want each subinterval to be smaller that $\delta$.

Comment: I think that'd be better. I haven't worked it out fully, but I think you'd run into trouble if your discontinuities were linearly independent in $\Bbb{R}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Also, the $2Mk \cdot (\varepsilon / 4Mk)$ term, I'm guessing that's your estimate for the rectangles around the discontinuities? You seem to be using $\varepsilon/4Mk$ as the length of the interval $(a_i - \varepsilon/4Mk, a_i + \varepsilon/4Mk)$, when it is actually double that.

Comment: @user771918 Yes sorry.

Comment: It is much simpler to observe that the interval of integration can be split into a finite number of subintervals sigh that each sub-interval contains only one point of discontinuity and that too as an end point of sub-interval. Thus the problem is reduced to the case when $f$ is discontinuous only at one of the end points of the interval of integration.